# OOP design in php

Tags: design, php, architecture

So I have to create an object design for this application, it is just problem for practicing.

> You are building application that will load data from several
>   different advertising systems and then store the data into database,
>   so it will be possible to analyze them.
>
> You need to take in mind that every advertising system has different
>   structure of report: Different named columns, different order of
>   columns, different date formats   Also data from ad systems are in
>   different data formats(JSON,CSV,XML),
>
> Reports from each system contains different amount of columns, our
>   application is interested only in some of them(in every system they
>   have different name)

I wrote this, only thing that is missing is method for selecting only columns that I need. Is this good structure ? I am new o OOP.

```
class Report {

    protected $data = [];
    protected $dataTypes = [];

    public function loadReport($adSystem){ return $data}

    public function loadAllReports($adSystemCollection){ return $data}

}

class Decode{

    protected $data = [];
    protected $dataTypes = [];

    public function getType($data){ return $dataTypes};
    public function getAllTypes($data){ return $dataTypes};
    public function getColumns($data, $columns){ return $data}
    public function convertToString($data,$dataTypes){ return $data}
    }
}

class Query{

    $databaseConnection = "";

    public function __construct(){
    //get database connection
     return void;
    }

    public function save($data){ return null};
    public function loadData($key){ return $data};
}

class Collection 
{
    private $items = array();

    public function addItem($obj, $key = null) {
    }

    public function deleteItem($key) {
    }

    public function getItem($key) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to analyzing the requirement/problem description and translating it into a decent and practical OOP design, the best approach is to identify the proper nouns and verbs in the given statement:

For example, here we have an **advertisement system** that has different **reports**. And each report has a different **format** and each report contains columns and date formats.

Then next step is to identify the relationships between them:

In your scenario, as each advertisement system aggregates different reports. So here we have aggregation (one to many relationship).

Study this tutorial here for more and precise details: [OOAD Tutorial](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333774/oop-design-in-php)

Identify the "is a" and "has a" relationship between the classes so wherever you come across "is a" relationship you would need a sub class i.e. you have to *inherit* a *child class* from the *base class*. In your case, there is no need for it. The "has a" relationship indicates aggregation or composition. And this is what I can see in your scenario as it is stated: *"Report **has a** format"*, *"Report **has a** column"*.

For a more clear explanation, go through this example: [Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation)

And in the final step, you have to identify the attributes of each class. For instance, here you have the **number of columns** that I would recommend that you should be including in your **Report** class.

But at the end of the day it all depends upon the core requirement in your application how your OOP design should be like.